# How to move cell data values from one column to another in HTML table with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to rotate the values in HTML table rows with button, but in the following code "Move" button is not working. Display button will give following table:

0 1 2
0 1 2
0 1 2
by clicking on move button I want table as follows:

2 0 1
2 0 1
2 0 1
and keep rotating the values in row by clicking the move button

```
<body>
<script>
var myArray = new Array();
var i=0;
var j=0;
function display()
{
var table = document.createElement('table');
table.setAttribute("id", "tbl");
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
  for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
      {
    var td= document.createElement('td');
    var text = document.createTextNode(j);

    td.appendChild(text);
    tr.appendChild(td);

    table.appendChild(tr);
    document.body.appendChild(table);
}
}
}

function move()
{
    var table = document.getElementById('tbl');
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
        var x = table.rows[i].cells[9].innerHTML;
        for(j=0;j<4;j++)
            {
    table.rows[i].cells[j+1].innerHTML = table.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML;  
        }
        table.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML=x;
    }
}

    </script>
```

HTML:

```
<input id="display" type="button" value="Display" onclick="display();" />
<input id="move" type="button" value="Move" onclick="move();" />
```

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific about "not working."

Comment: Your table element isn't being generated with an id in the display function. when you go to the move function there is no element with id "table", and it throws an error. If you fix this it'll do something. Though I'm not sure that's what you want. What do you mean by shifting?

Comment: shifting means I want to rotate the values in row one by one.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show what you are trying to accomplish? It is still unclear what you mean by rotating the values one by one.

Comment: I have edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe:

```js
function display() {
    var table = document.createElement('table');

    table.setAttribute("id", "tbl");

    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            var td = document.createElement('td');
            var text = document.createTextNode(j);

            td.appendChild(text);
            tr.appendChild(td);
        }
        table.appendChild(tr);
    }
    document.body.appendChild(table);
}

function move() {
    var table = document.querySelector('#tbl');
    var tr = table.rows;

    for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        tr[i].insertBefore(tr[i].lastElementChild, tr[i].firstElementChild);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! As the move function does rotation from left to right. How to modify the function for rotation in opposite direction i.e. from right to left.

Comment: `tr[i].appendChild(tr[i].firstElementChild);`